# Model Serialization in H2O.ai Sparkling Water

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

Do you guys already worked with serialized models in Sparkling Models ou export models like the Spark to put in production? How can I do that?!

Thanks in advance.

Flavio

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways how you can export a model.

You can export binary version( serialization) of model, POJO ( Plain Old Java Object) and Mojo ( Model Object Optimised)

You can read more about POJOs and MOJOs here. These 2 are used for putting models into predictions. The good thing about them that they don't need H2O framework to be running.

The methods you can use for exporting are available here https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/water/support/ModelSerializationSupport.scala

`exportH2OModel` exports binary model and `exportPOJOModel` exports POJO.

The method for exporting MOJO is accidentally missing and will be added in the next Sparkling Water release.